# Angular 6 timer -- for session handling

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular6

I have a scenario to handle session in Angular application. Here is what I am trying to acheive.

1) Have a class implement HttpInterceptor so that I can initiate a timer(starting at 0Sec) on ever successful response and increment the timer till 30mins. If there isnt any server call in between the timer, I want to warn user that session is gonna expire.
3) I am trying to user Rxjs interval concept here -- not sure this is what I need to use. Please see the below code

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpRequest, HttpSentEvent, HttpHandler, HttpProgressEvent, HttpResponse, HttpUserEvent, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer'
import { tap } from 'rxjs/Operators';
import { pipe, observable, interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class NoopInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { 
    //assuming to reset the timer here again to 0 sec
    this.stopInterval();
  }
  event : Observable<any>;
  subscription: Subscription;

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
    console.log("Inside the interceptor");
    return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(event => {
      if(event instanceof Response){
       if(event.status == 200){
        this.timer();
        }
      }
      }));
    }

    timer() {
     this.subscription = interval(1000).subscribe(
       //wait for 30mins here and give warning to  user
       val=>console.log("----------"+val));
    }
    stopInterval() {
      console.log("--unscubscribing ---")
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Removed java tag

Answer (score 0):

Think the approach is ok, code can be simplified a little. Maybe you can try use interval with `take(30)` to limit to 30sec (althougth interval is not 100 percent accurate timer)

```
export class NoopInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { 
    //assuming to reset the timer here again to 0 sec
    this.stopInterval();
  }
  event : Observable<any>;
  subscription: Subscription=this.timer.subscribe();
  timer=interval(1000).pipe(take(30),tap(()=>console.log('warning session expire'))

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
    console.log("Inside the interceptor");
    return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(event => {
      if(event instanceof Response){
       if(event.status == 200){
          this.subscription.unsubscribe()
          this.subscription=this.timer.subscribe()    
        }
      }
      }));
    }

}
```